# Fibonacci series through serial code

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I am interested in knowing what actual execution time it takes for the following fibonacci serial code to execute when I input n=40???

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printFibonacci(int);

int main(){

    int k,n;
    long int i=0,j=1,f;

    printf("Enter the range of the Fibonacci series: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Fibonacci Series: ");
    printf("%d %d ",0,1);
    printFibonacci(n);

    return 0;
}

void printFibonacci(int n){

    static long int first=0,second=1,sum;

    if(n>0){
         sum = first + second;
         first = second;
         second = sum;
         printf("%ld ",sum);
         printFibonacci(n-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: So what's your question?  How to get execution time?  On Linux, you can use "time".

Comment: "actual execution time": why don't you **MEASURE**? but beware, most of the actual execution time will be spent in the i/o. it will not be very meaningful.

Comment: It would be in a flash anyway...

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can measure a program's execution time using the "time" command:

- http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm

On Windows, you can can download "timer.exe" from the Windows Resource Kit, or use one of these "tricks":

- https://superuser.com/questions/228056/windows-equivalent-to-unix-time-command

Answer (score 0):

Using the time command won't work well here, because it would include user's input time, not the algorithm itself.

On Windows, I would use combination of QueryPerformanceFrequency and QueryPerformanceCounter.

```
#include <windows.h>

__int64 before, after, freq;
QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER *)&freq);
QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&before);

printFibonacci(n);

QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&after);

int elapsedMs = ((after - before) * 1000) / freq;

printf("Time taken: %dms\n", elapsedMs);
```

Linux provides another set of functions:

```
#include <time.h>

int clock_getres(clockid_t clock_id, struct timespec *res);
int clock_gettime(clockid_t clock_id, struct timespec *tp);
int clock_settime(clockid_t clock_id, const struct timespec *tp);
```

Here's an example how to use these: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref/c/clock_getres.html